# SFS file not found error when booting live Puppy Linux

Tags: boot, multi-boot, usb-flash-drive, puppylinux

This is a very old problem that is still with us ([Puppy Linux cannot boot](https://superuser.com/questions/637026/puppy-linux-cannot-boot) and http://www.murga-linux.com/puppy/viewtopic.php?t=84558 are 4 years old; an 8-year-old posting exists).

There are many solutions posted and none of them work for me. In my case, I'm trying to boot to a live USB flash drive of Tahrpup (tahr-6.0.5.iso) installed on the flash drive using a Windows computer by running unetbootin-windows-657.exe. All software is 32 bits, and the USB drive is 8 GB formatted FAT32. The target computer is Asus HE1000 with 1 GB of RAM and around 200 GB per disk partition. Creation of the live Linux Puppy flash drive was done on a Windows 8.1 computer.

When booting, the "sfs file not found" error message happens no matter what "solution" I find on the Web that I try. And alternate boots switch between Windows XP on the C: hard drive and puppy on the USB flash drive no matter how I set the BIOS, so the power button has to be held down for a long time twice for each boot of puppy. So frustrating; need advanced help.

Comment: I've given up on using Linux other than on remote webservers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I noticed. During the install, when it asks "Do you want to have a install with a initial RAM disk (initrd.gz)?"

Answer "No", because the default install of the initrd.gz look for a USB storage mounted device, which isn't there when installed.

Answer (score 1):

I have "slacko-6.3.2.sfs file not found" problem with Slacko 6.3.2 (but file IS on drive). Before Puppy Linux work good for three years (2016 - 2019), then today I have this boot problem. I think problem happen because try install different Puppy Linux (Bionic Puppy) on this drive.

Solution: I erase whole USB drive then reinstall Slacko 6.3.2 use slacko-6.3.2-uefi.iso use Unetbootin and USB drive boot normal again.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Tryed different USB creating tools without luck. I am using 16G usb drive (smallest I was able to find these days). Then I thought maybe this is the problem. I used Partition Magic to resize it to 4G. Fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with "slacko-6.3.2.sfs file not found". I booted from another flash drive "mint7" and formatted the partition using Gparted. After that, everything became good.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the well-known error:

> /puppy_fossapup64 9.5.sfs not found.

My grub2 `menuentry` needed fixing.

---

Context: I have a `NVMe` ssd setup in a `GPT` partition. Puppy Linux files were copied inside a folder called `puppy` on a `ext2` formatted drive.
I already have Manjaro installed & had to add the following `menuentry` to my grub2 config:
`/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

This is what worked for me (obviously the values are specific to my scenario):

```
menuentry 'Puppy Linux' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 22bc847d-307b-4bfb-b874-fce7c4a6c571
        linux   /puppy/vmlinuz pmedia=nvmeblk psubdir=puppy
        initrd  /puppy/initrd.gz
}
```

- `insmod part_gpt` - GPT partition
- `insmod ext2` - Puppy Linux files are in a `ext2` formatted partition
- `22bc847d-307b-4bfb-b874-fce7c4a6c571` - name of the partition
- `linux /puppy/vmlinuz` - file path of `vmlinuz`; it's inside `puppy` folder
- `linux ... pmedia=nvmeblk` - my drive is nvme
- `linux ... psubdir=puppy` - my root folder name is `puppy`

---

For reference, `lsblk -a` was:

```
nvme0n1     259:0    0 465.8G  0 disk  
├─...  
└─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0     4G  0 part /run/media/REDACTED/22bc847d-307b-4bfb-b874-fce7c4a6c571
```

and `tree` was:

```
/run/media/REDACTED/22bc847d-307b-4bfb-b874-fce7c4a6c571  
└── puppy  
    ├── adrv_fossapup64_9.5.sfs  
    ├── fdrv_fossapup64_9.5.sfs  
    ├── initrd.gz  
    ├── puppy_fossapup64_9.5.sfs  
    ├── vmlinuz  
    └── zdrv_fossapup64_9.5.sfs
```